# Upgrade ESXi 6.5 installed on USB flash drive to 6.5 Update 2

Tags: vmware-esxi

My ESXi 6.5 server boots from a USB flash drive. Is the upgrade process any different, when installed on the USB stick, from upgrading when ESXi is installed on a hard drive?

I wondered if it would be easier to just replace the USB stick with one containing the updated ESXI, but the old USB stick probably contains the settings (for the server, VMs & datastores), so I would need somehow to copy these across. Would this be easier than the first method?

Answer (score -2):

I created a new bootable USB flash drive containing ESXi 6.5 Update 2. I booted the server from this, set the IP address then re-registered all the VMs. Was amazingly simple.

Before starting, it is important to make a list of the VMs to register!